# Control does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is something simple that I am just overlooking, but I can't figure it out. I am new to C# and I'm trying to create a calculator application. I have created my form with all of my buttons/textbox on it. Now I'm creating a new class to handle all of my methods and whatnot. My problem is that whenever I'm trying to reference controls on the form in the second class, I get the "does not exist in the current context" error. How can I solve this?

An example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        decimal currentValue = Decimal.Parse(displayValue.text);

    }
}
```

displayValue receives the error. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controls can be called only from the `.cs` file  which is linked with the form controls.

What you can do is create a parameterized constructor of your `Calculator` class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public Calculator(string displayValue)
        {
            decimal currentValue = Decimal.Parse(displayValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can call this class in the form `.cs` where you  have buttons and textboxes like this:

```
Calculator calculate = new Calculator(displayValue.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Windows Form Application, there's a designer (which you can interact with to add your buttons and textboxes) and the code-behind (a .cs file).

This .cs file is a partial class, meaning it is also defined by the form you are interacting with. (you can see the nitty gritty details in your .Designer.cs file)

Once you name your buttons and textboxes, you can refer to their names in the code in your partial class!

[image: form] [image: code]

And when you compile this, your button text will change to "Hello World!"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this control in partial class of the form. You can take values from it and do your operation

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = textBox1.Text;
    }
  }
```